# Networking with Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, docker

I used this official guide to set up Docker on a Windows 7 machine:

https://docs.docker.com/windows/started/

I successfully pulled an image from the docker hub and I can run my own docker image.

No I am stuck trying to run and access a webserver with docker on Windows. Apparently, behind `boot2docker` I can't reach my docker container the way I was used to.

Once I added `-p 3007:80` to the `docker run` command, the port forwarding showed up in the container list (`docker ps`) as `0.0.0.0:3007 -> 80`. And with `-p 127.0.0.1:3007:80` I get a more meaningful ip address. I cannot, however, reach the container with a browser on the Windows host.

Moreover, `docker inspect` does not reveal an ip address for the running container (which also seems wrong).

I also tried `--net=host` to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things changed a little with the introduction of Docker Toolbox. Now you do not directly interact with `boot2docker`, but instead use `docker-machine`. Although `boot2docker` still exists as VM there is no CLI-Tool any longer. It was replaced by Docker Machine.

Thus you should be able to get hold of the VM's IP address by typing: `docker-machine ip <machine-name>`. If you do have the default installation your machine name will be `default`.

With `docker-machine active` you can have a look which VM is currently active. With that name you can also use `docker-machine inspect <machine-name>`.

You can find more about Docker Machine in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/).

Comment: Thanks! `docker-machine ip default` was the step I was missing. Not obvious in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Things changed more than just a little by now: Docker supports Windows natively and Boot2Docker or Docker Toolbox aren´t needed anymore. You should start with [Windows 10](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) (or Windows Server 2016) now.

Throughout my Docker on Windows journey I developed a best practice to check, if a webserver is accessible:

1. Run your container (e.g. with your mentioned `docker run -d -p hostport:containerport imagename`)
2. Shell into the container (e.g. with a Windows Container: `docker exec -it containerName powershell` or `docker exec -it containerName bash`, if you use Linux containers) and check, if `iwr http://localhost:80 -UseBasicParsing` gives you a good looking HTML and HTTP Status 200
3. If 2. went fine (and only then), check the IP of your container (e.g. with `docker network inspect dockerNetworkName`, which´ll give you all your containers data including the internal IP addresses) and point your Browser to `http://containerIP:containerPort`.
4. If 3. went fine (and again: only then), check if you could reach your webserver with `http://localhost:containerPort` (this maybe doesn´t work for Windows containers, because the [localhost loopback isn´t working](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/458) - although it could work on newer versions of Windows 10/Server 2016)
5. Final step (if 1., 2. & 3. went fine, 4. optional), try to lookup your webserver from outside the Windows host (e.g. if you´re running a Windows host inside Virtual Box, mind the port forwarding configuration!)